# Python Image to Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

i'm trying to write a python script that will take an image as an input and print out whatever is in the image as text to the terminal or a file. i do have python 2.7 and 3.7 
i do have PIL and pytesseract install on my Kali linux

but i'm getting this errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):



File "imgtotxt.py", line 8, in <module>
img =Image.open("/home/Desktop/ITT/1.jpeg")


 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2609, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/Desktop/ITT/1.jpeg'
```

HERE IS MY CODE

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
img =Image.open("/home/Desktop/ITT/1.jpeg")
text =image_to_string(img)
print (text)
```

Comment: Well, the message is clear, no file with this name exists. You probably have your username between `home` and `Desktop`...

Comment: that's the exact path to the file

Comment: Your username is `Desktop`? Usually there's a folder with the user name under `/home`. Try with `~/Desktop/ITT/1.jpeg` instead and see if it works.

Comment: i opened the terminal from the folder where the image is but it doesn't still work

Comment: i am on linux not windows. my file path doesn't have a user name /home/Desktop/

Comment: Type `pwd` in the terminal from the folder containing the image. What do you get?

Comment: /root/Desktop/ITT

Comment: So it's `/root`, not `/home`. Also, you shouldn't work as root, use a normal user account.

Comment: the errors are even more now. do you know any other modules that could make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if the file exists at the exact location you specified.  The system isn't finding the file.  Perhaps it's at /home/YOUR_USER/Desktop/ITT/1.jpeg ?

Comment: Yes, that is where the image is

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with how you typed the filename.

Try this in your python code:

```
import os
print(os.listdir("/home/Desktop/ITT/"))
```

You *should* see your filename printed. Copy the filename from there instead.

If this fails, go up a directory (eg `/home/Desktop`) and try that.

Comment: @TchemedjeRhonnelYvan Yes. So the problem is the directory. Go to your command line. type `cd ~` that should bring you to home. then cd to Desktop, etc.Once you are where you want, type `pwd`.

Comment: @TchemedjeRhonnelYvan try what i wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script in the same folder as is the image, change path to only a name of the image and you will se if something is REALLY wrong.

EDIT:

Try this then:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread('1.jpeg') # alternativly /home/Desktop/ITT/
img = Image.fromarray(image.astype(np.uint8))
....
```

Also check if your image is not corrupted. This is pretty strange